# Override module variable in python that uses other module variable

Tags: python-3.x, variables, module

I have a python module, where i store my settings `settings.py`. This files contains lines like

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_URL = 'https://my-base-url.com/test'
...
SCORM_TEST_URL = BASE_URL + '/scorm2004testwrap.htm'
```

I want to allow users to override these settings e.g. by using command line options or environment variables. It works well for direct variable assignments when I do

```
import settings
settings.BASE_URL = 'test'
```

However

```
settings.SCORM_TEST_URL 
#will print https://my-base-url.com/test/scorm2004testwrap.htm
```

Is there a way to tell python to update these dependant variables with the overridden values? Or how can I design my program, that it allows overriding of settings and as well setting variables in files that are python modules, because as you see it might need other python modules imports like `os` in the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is not something doable

When you set `setting.BASE_URL = something`, its being reassign to something now and whatever previous value is gone so it works.

But `SCORM_TEST_URL` is created based on old `BASE_URL` value, its has no relation to `BASE_URL` once its created.Thus, changing `BASE_URL` won't reflect on `SCORM_TEST_URL` unless you reevaluate it based on new `BASE_URL` value.

Some workaround i can think of as below, declare those variable that need to modify outside module as usual.

Put another set of variable that needs to be updated inside an update function and make them as global

Inside settings.py

```
BASE_URL = 'https://my-base-url.com/test'
# ... other var

def update_var():
    global SCORM_TEST_URL
    SCORM_TEST_URL = BASE_URL + '/scorm2004testwrap.htm'
    # added other var accordingly
```

From other module, import settings as usual

```
import settings
settings.BASE_URL = 'test'
# update variables
settings.update_var()
# settings.SCORM_TEST_URL should be updated now
```